Why is this Shiny uiOutput block not executing? How can I get this slider to show up dynamically?
I want a sliderInput to show up only after the user uploads a CSV file, and the max value of the input to be set to the number of rows in the CSV file. For testing, I'm just using a CSV file with 15 random numbers. It seems simple enough, but I can't get it working. I've been using print dialogs to try to debug, and I'm finding the upload works fine and all the print lines in the observeEvents block print as expected, but the print line within the renderUI call NEVER prints.  It's just not executing that code block. Why?
Here's an MRE:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Bootstrap Sample Size Simulator"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # Define the primary inputs needed to setup the sample size simulation
            fileInput("file_upload", "Upload a CSV file with sample data to use for sample size optimization:", accept = ".csv"),
            uiOutput("slider_output")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            ##EMPTY###
        )
    )
)

#### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Create reactive values for the file upload
    upload <- reactiveValues(
        isUploaded = FALSE, # flag signifying the file has been uploaded
        data = NULL # empty placeholder for the data
    )
    
    sample_max <- reactive({
        NULL  # Initially set to NULL
        if (is.null(upload$data)) return(NULL) # return NULL if uploadedData is NULL
        nrow(upload$data)
    })
    
    # define function for the slider UI element for sample size limit selection
    slider_ui <- function() {
        if (upload$isUploaded()) {
            sliderInput("sample_range",
                        label = "Range of Sample Sizes to simulate from the uploaded data:",
                        min = 2,
                        max = sample_max(),
                        value = c(2, sample_max())
            )
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    }
    
    # Update reactive values and show slider when file is uploaded
    observeEvent(input$file_upload, {
        #print("inside observEvent")
        upload$isUploaded <- TRUE  # Set flag to TRUE after upload
        #print(paste("isUploaded:",upload$isUploaded))
        upload$data <- read.csv(input$file_upload$datapath) # read the uploaded CSV file
        sample_max <- nrow(upload$data) # update sample_max after successful upload
        #print(paste("sample_max:",sample_max))
        #print(head(upload$data))
    })
    
    # Render the slider element conditionally
    output$sliderOutput <- reactive({
        renderUI({
            print("inside RenderUI for sliderOutput")
            slider_ui()
        })
    })
}

#### APP ####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


You're assigning a reactive to output and defining your renderUI locally within the reactive.  That's a recipe for disaster.  I'll try to provide a working solution as and when I have the time.  And you have uiOutput("slider_output") vs output$sliderOutput.

Ahh. Thanks!  I've refactored this a number of times. Outside reactive, inside reactive, using conditionalPanel, etc. Good catch!

There are a few issues, looking at individual lines:
(1) In ui object:
uiOutput("slider_output") should be uiOutput("sliderOutput")
This is because "sliderOutput" is the value you're assigning to the output object within the server block.
(2) In slider_ui function:
if (upload$isUploaded()) should be if (upload$isUploaded)
This is because you are using reactiveValues instead of reactiveVal (the latter returns a function, but the former references its defined veraibles as a regular list using $)
(3) In the server block:
output$sliderOutput <- reactive({
        renderUI({
            print("inside RenderUI for sliderOutput")
            slider_ui()
        })
    })

Should be
output$sliderOutput <- renderUI({
      print("inside RenderUI for sliderOutput")
      slider_ui()
  })

The "render" class of functions should be assigned to the server's output object.  Whereas a reactive() expression should be assigned to a variable that you want to make outputs or observers responsive to.
